# What does ${foo#?} mean in a bash script?

Tags: bash

Can someone tell me what the following line

```
tmp="${dirname#?}
```

is doing in the script below:

```
#!/bin/sh
appname=`basename $0 | sed s,\.sh$,,`

dirname=`dirname $0`
tmp="${dirname#?}"

if [ "${dirname%$tmp}" != "/" ]; then
dirname=$PWD/$dirname
fi
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$dirname
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
$dirname/$appname "$@"
```

It seems to remove the leading '/', but I can't find any documentation for the #? operator.

Comment: Hint: In this context, it's a more general way to write `${dirname#/}`, which arguably would be more readable and safer in this use case.

Comment: See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

Comment: Check the man page for `${parameter#word}` in the "Parameter Expansion" section. `?` here is just the pattern metacharacter that matches any single character.

Comment: BTW, there are some bugs in here around lack of quoting (http://shellcheck.net/ would catch them), and using `sed` here is just silly; if you're going to use `basename` anyhow, why not let it take the extension off too?

Comment: that is to say: `appname=$(basename "$0" .sh)` if you're going to be using external tools anyhow, or: `appname=${0##*/}; appname=${0%.sh}` otherwise.

Comment: (Also, don't use `.sh` extensions for scripts; UNIX command names shouldn't have extensions -- that's why you run `ls`, not `ls.elf`).

Comment: Got it! Just got this off the internet. But I'll make the recommended edits now that I understand what's going on. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`${var#?}` expands to the value of `$var`, with the first character removed.

In general, `${var#substring}` removes the shortest occurrence of substring from the start of the variable `$var`. `?` is a special character, which means *any character*.

This feature is documented on [this page of the bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) (look for `${parameter#word}`).

Comment: BTW: what is the last line doing: $dirname/$appname "$@"

Comment: It is executing the command with path `$dirname/$appname` (which should be wrapped in quotes like `"$dirname/$appname"`), passing through the arguments which were given to this script.

Comment: Okay, so when this last command executes, will it be in another sub-shell? I ask because, the EXPORT command does not affect the current shell.

Comment: @GMahan it's a separate process - the fact that it may be a shell script doesn't make any difference. My understanding is that any environment variables set in that script will be lost when it finishes. Any environment variables set in the parent should be visible to the child process.